# Streaming to adobe media server

Tags: streaming, adobe, media

i have adobe media server on my laptop. I want to stream videos to it from some other laptop. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Flash Media Encoder ( FME ) on a computer where you capture a videosource ( camera ) to push the stream to FMS.
With vlc you can transcode almost any video format to x264/rtp.
You can develop flash application which will capture the laptop camera and push it tou your server.
Other server software, like WOwza with its "PushToCdn" plugin, can handle a variety of video sources and push them to your server.

Comment: My problem is that how can i push it to my other laptop? because when i do it on my laptop, i just give localhost in the url for streaming. what do i give as url now?

Comment: Does your laptop have a network connection? If yes you can retrieve the ip address running ipconfig /all in a command prompt